# can't get JQUERY .autocomplete to work right with .attr

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

I'm going around and around in circles on this. I'm new to JQUERY and so far it's awesome! I've looked over tons of stuff on the internet and here in the answered questions but I have not been able to figure out the right answer. Right now I'm killing myself trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong on it. The .autocomplete is working fine with the basic stuff like giving me back a string from the MYSQL database and inputing it into form how I want. But the problem I'm having is bringing back a boolean value and marking a check box with that value. What I'm getting right now is all the boxes checked even if the value if 0.

### Here's my .autocomplete code.

```
<?php require_once('../connection.php'); ?>
<?php include '../_includes/jq.inc.php';?>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#Company_Name').val("");
    $('#Manager').val("");
    $('#Phone').val("");
    $('#Contacted').val("");
    $('#Pitched').val("");
    $('#Interested').val("");
           $("#autoSearch").autocomplete({
                source: "Test.QUERY.php",
                minLength: 2,
                select: function(event, ui) {
                        $('#Company_Name').val(ui.item.Company_Name);
                        $('#Manager').val(ui.item.Manager);
                        $('#Phone').val(ui.item.Phone);
                        $('#Contacted').attr("checked", true);
                        $('#Pitched').attr("checked", true);
                        $('#Interested').attr("checked", true);
                }
            });
     }); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>"  method="post">SEARCH:
<input type="text" id="autoSearch" size="60" onClick="this.form.reset()"/>
</form>
<form method="POST" name="form">
<input type="text" name="Company_Name" id="Company_Name">Company Name<br>
<input type="text" name="Manager" id="Manager">Manager<br>
<input type="text"  name="Phone" id="Phone">Phone<br>
Contacted<input type="checkbox" name="Contacted" id="Contacted"><br>
Pitched<input type="checkbox" name="Pitched" id="Pitched"><br>
Interested<input type="checkbox" name="Interested" id="Interested">
<br>
<input type="submit" name="button" value="UPDATE">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

### Here's how the MYSQL DB is set for the next QUERY

```
Company_Name  varchar(45)
Manager       varchar(45)
Phone         varchar(45)
Contacted     tinyint(1)
Pitched       tinyint(1)
Interested    tinyint(1)
```

### Here's the Test.QUERY.php Page

```
<?php include_once '../conn.php';?>
<?php
try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
$return_arr = array();

if ($conn)
{
    $ac_term = "%".$_GET['term']."%"; 
    $query = "SELECT
Company_Name, Manager, Phone, Contacted, Pitched, Interested,
CONCAT_WS(' ', Company_Name, Manager, Phone) AS autoNameShow
FROM CustomerList
WHERE `Company_Name` LIKE :term
    OR `Manager` LIKE :term
    OR `Phone` LIKE :term
";
    $result = $conn->prepare($query);
    $result->bindValue(":term",$ac_term);
    $result->execute(); 

    while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        
        $row_array['value'] = $row['autoNameShow'];
        $row_array['Company_Name'] = $row['Company_Name'];
        $row_array['Manager'] = $row['Manager'];
        $row_array['Phone'] = $row['Phone'];    
        $row_array['Contacted'] = $row['Contacted'];
        $row_array['Pitched'] = $row['Pitched'];
        $row_array['Interested'] = $row['Interested'];

        array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
    }

}
$conn = null;
echo json_encode($return_arr);
?>
```

So, the million dollar question is..... What did I do wrong & how should I fix it?

### EDIT from Suggestion.

### QUERY PAGE

```
<?php include_once '../conn.php';?>
<?php
try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

$return_arr = array();

if ($conn)
{
    $ac_term = "%".$_GET['term']."%"; 
    $query = "SELECT
Company_Name, Manager, Phone, Contacted, Pitched, Interested,
CONCAT_WS(' ', Company_Name, Manager, Phone) AS autoNameShow
FROM CustomerList
WHERE `Company_Name` LIKE :term
    OR `Manager` LIKE :term
    OR `Phone` LIKE :term
";
    $result = $conn->prepare($query);
    $result->bindValue(":term",$ac_term);
    $result->execute(); 

    while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $return_arr[] = array(
        'value' => $row['autoNameShow'],
        'Company_Name' => $row['Company_Name'],
        'Manager' => $row['Manager'],
        'Phone' => $row['Phone'],
        'Contacted' => $row['Contacted'],
        'Pitched' => $row['Pitched'],
        'Interested' => $row['Interested'],
  
    );
}}
$conn = null;
echo json_encode($return_arr);
?>
```

### autocomplete page

```
<?php include '../_includes/jq.inc.php';?>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var $form = $('#my_form');

$(function() { 
    $('#Company_Name').val("");
    $('#Manager').val("");
    $('#Phone').val("");
    $('#Contacted').val("");
    $('#Pitched').val("");
    $('#Interested').val("");
    
    $('#autoSearch').autocomplete({
    source: 'Test.QUERY.php',
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $form.find('input').val('');
        $form.find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', '');

        $('#Company_Name').val(ui.item.Company_Name);
        $('#Manager').val(ui.item.Manager);
        $('#Phone').val(ui.item.Phone);

        if (ui.item.Contacted) { $('#Contacted').attr('checked', 'checked'); }
        if (ui.item.Pitched) { $('#Pitched').attr('checked', 'checked'); }
        if (ui.item.Interested) { $('#Interested').attr('checked', 'checked'); }
    }
});
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>"  method="post">SEARCH:
<input type="text" id="autoSearch" size="60" onClick="this.form.reset()"/>
</form>
<form method="POST" name="form" id="my_form">
<input type="text" name="Company_Name" id="Company_Name">Company Name<br>
<input type="text" name="Manager" id="Manager">Manager<br>
<input type="text"  name="Phone" id="Phone">Phone<br>
Contacted<input type="checkbox" name="Contacted" id="Contacted"><br>
Pitched<input type="checkbox" name="Pitched" id="Pitched"><br>
Interested<input type="checkbox" name="Interested" id="Interested">
<br>
<input type="submit" name="button" value="UPDATE"> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

### Still getting all the boxes checked.

What am I doing wrong?

### Also posting the JSON return data.

```
[{"value":"Company Test 1 Manager Test 1 111-111-1111","Company_Name":"Company Test 1","Manager":"Manager Test 1","Phone":"111-111-1111","Contacted":"0","Pitched":"0","Interested":"0"},{"value":"Company Test 2 Manager Test 2 222-222-2222","Company_Name":"Company Test 2","Manager":"Manager Test 2","Phone":"222-222-2222","Contacted":"0","Pitched":"1","Interested":"1"},{"value":"Company Test 3 Manager Test 3 333-333-3333","Company_Name":"Company Test 3","Manager":"Manager Test 3","Phone":"333-333-3333","Contacted":"0","Pitched":"0","Interested":"1"},{"value":"Company Test 4 Manager Test 4 444-444-4444","Company_Name":"Company Test 4","Manager":"Manager Test 4","Phone":"444-444-4444","Contacted":"1","Pitched":"0","Interested":"1"},{"value":"Company Test 5 Manager Test 5 555-555-5555","Company_Name":"Company Test 5","Manager":"Manager Test 5","Phone":"555-555-5555","Contacted":"0","Pitched":"1","Interested":"1"},{"value":"Company Test 6 Manager Test 6 666-666-6666","Company_Name":"Company Test 6","Manager":"Manager Test 6","Phone":"666-666-6666","Contacted":"1","Pitched":"0","Interested":"1"},{"value":"Company Test 7 Manager Test 7 777-777-7777","Company_Name":"Company Test 7","Manager":"Manager Test 7","Phone":"777-777-7777","Contacted":"0","Pitched":"1","Interested":"1"},{"value":"Company Test 8 Manager Test 8 888-888-8888","Company_Name":"Company Test 8","Manager":"Manager Test 8","Phone":"888-888-8888","Contacted":"1","Pitched":"0","Interested":"1"},{"value":"Company Test 9 Manager Test 9 999-999-9999","Company_Name":"Company Test 9","Manager":"Manager Test 9","Phone":"999-999-9999","Contacted":"0","Pitched":"1","Interested":"0"},{"value":"Company Test 10 Manager Test 10 000-000-0000","Company_Name":"Company Test 10","Manager":"Manager Test 10","Phone":"000-000-0000","Contacted":"1","Pitched":"0","Interested":"1"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Thank you all for your suggestions! Here's what I came up with from them all.

```
select: function(event, ui) {
  $('#Company_Name').val(ui.item.Company_Name);
  $('#Manager').val(ui.item.Manager);
  $('#Phone').val(ui.item.Phone);
     
 if (ui.item.Contacted == "1") {
  $('#Contacted').prop('checked', true);
 } else {
  $('#Contacted').prop('checked', false);
 }
 if (ui.item.Pitched == "1") {
  $('#Pitched').prop('checked', true);
 } else {
  $('#Pitched').prop('checked', false);
 }
 if (ui.item.Interested == "1") {
  $('#Interested').prop('checked', true);
 } else {
  $('#Interested').prop('checked', false);
 }
}
```

## Now that is works, any ideas on how to make it more compact? :) Thanks Again!

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8470229/1076353) has a more compact solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

When you are selecting a value from the autocomplete list, You’re automatically checking all three checkboxes regardless of the value that is returned.

You’ll want to use something like:

```
var $form = $('#my_form');

$('#autoSearch').autocomplete({
    source: 'Test.QUERY.php',
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $form.find('input').val('');
        $form.find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', '');

        $('#Company_Name').val(ui.item.Company_Name);
        $('#Manager').val(ui.item.Manager);
        $('#Phone').val(ui.item.Phone);

        if (ui.item.Contacted == "1") {
            $('#Contacted').attr('checked', 'checked');
        }

        if (ui.item.Pitched == "1") {
            $('#Pitched').attr('checked', 'checked');
        }

        if (ui.item.Interested == "1") {
            $('#Interested').attr('checked', 'checked');
        }
    }
});
```

Your form would need an ID:

```
<form method="POST" name="form" id="my_form">
    <input type="text" name="Company_Name" id="Company_Name"> Company Name<br />
    ...
</form>
```

A minor note on your PHP code, you can use the following code to assing to the $return_arr array rather than using array_push.

```
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $return_arr[] = array(
        'value' => $row['autoNameShow'],
        'Company_Name' => $row['Company_Name'],
        'Manager' => $row['Manager'],
        'Phone' => $row['Phone'],
        // ... etc
    );
}
```

Comment: I did your suggestions. I'm still getting all the check boxes checked. See EDIT.

Comment: Are you using Firebug? -- Put a breakpoint in last if statement of the select function and see what the value of ui.item.Interested/Pitched/Contacted is... if it's checking the boxes, that means that those values are returning with something other than '0', '', null, empty or false.

Comment: Yeah, it selects the boxes each time I Step Into it.

Comment: Check out the JSON data thats returned.

Comment: Try using: `if (ui.item.Contacted == "1")` (And the same for the other two checkboxes), but using the same code above... that should achieve the desired results. It seems that "0" may be evaluating to "true" and thus checking the boxes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery 1.6 or higher, you need to use `.prop` for checkboxes instead of `.attr`. If you MUST use `.attr`, the correct syntax is `.attr('checked', 'checked')`

Comment: Using .prop does the same thing. Returns all boxes as checked. I'm missing something basic here I'm sure.

Comment: @Darcy - As long as any value is set for the attribute checked, it will be checked, e.g. .attr('checked', 'Darcy'). Even .attr('checked', '') will check it off and to really throw off people .attr('checked', false) will however uncheck it. ?I didn't look, but I believe internally jQuery does a removeAttr('checked') when it is set to false. Before XHTML the attribute in markup was just <input type="checkbox" checked /> but when XHTML came around, they did this to accomodate it, <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />.

Answer (score 0):

You explicitly check all your checkboxes with this code :

```
$('#Contacted').attr("checked", true);
$('#Pitched').attr("checked", true);
$('#Interested').attr("checked", true);
```

It's actually normal that what you are "getting right now is all the boxes checked".

Comment: All that does for me is it returns ALL the boxes checked. I want them checked only if the values in MYSQL is 1 as true, or not checked if the value comes back 0 as false. This is also happening when I use .prop.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your autocomplete to pick out the checkbox items instead of setting them to checked:

```
$(function() {
    $('#Company_Name').val("");
    $('#Manager').val("");
    $('#Phone').val("");
    $('#Contacted')[0].checked = false;
    $('#Pitched')[0].checked = false;
    $('#Interested')[0].checked = false;
    $("#autoSearch").autocomplete({
                source: "Test.QUERY.php",
                minLength: 2,
                select: function(event, ui) {
                        $('#Company_Name').val(ui.item.Company_Name);
                        $('#Manager').val(ui.item.Manager);
                        $('#Phone').val(ui.item.Phone);
                        $('#Contacted')[0].checked = ui.item.Contacted;
                        $('#Pitched')[0].checked = ui.item.Pitched;
                        $('#Interested')[0].checked = ui.item.Interested;
                }
    });
});
```

My assumption here is that the ui.item.Contacted etc contain the true/false values.
You could put a `console.log(ui.item.Company_name+ ":"+ui.item.Contacted);` in the select to test those values or simply `alert(ui.item.Company_name+ ":"+ui.item.Contacted);`

Comment: Thank you for this. I tried it but I get the same thing back. All boxes are checked. None of the MYSQL date has all fields true or false. They are all mixed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more compact version of [the solution you came up with](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7908683/1076353).

```
select: function(event, ui) {
    $('#Company_Name').val(ui.item.Company_Name);
    $('#Manager').val(ui.item.Manager);
    $('#Phone').val(ui.item.Phone);

    $('#Contacted').prop('checked', ui.item.Contacted == '1');
    $('#Pitched').prop('checked', ui.item.Pitched == '1');
    $('#Interested').prop('checked', ui.item.Interested == '1');
}
```